# Excluding the last element from the expression to for each controller

Tags: jmeter

Have this situation for my script, using the following regular expression I am getting 14 file name from which I want to send 13 file name to for each controller and last file name an another transaction, how to do it in JMeter?

Regex Expression Details:

```
Variable Name :  FileName
Expression : <file name='(.+?)' size=
Template : $1$
Match Number : -1
```

And obtained following 14 file name :

```
dc592db8421a4962ae1a6443528798b8
9107c0cfcafb4432b1b23ab4376e4270
afa2c15cbfb343dc9f7ce86c8d8060c7
92fadeb05ca24d17b9652f7d7cb0f0f9
13ce49eae6b844fc83465a75993cf189
f874a5d36af440b18890093b2f66567e
b565639b8dd041278680dec9a7571df4
276b5e6ac31c436bbb34eeb1746d2a9a
5a51c36aed5b4e5c95088c3b05f4dd43
3029107b05ec4879bbde5b83d59ddae6
3b1eb34f07424709a1416239a7ef95f4
dc82aed56e7547f6adfe141e7898ac77
8df540bfff8e489b978a0d5bbfd2f475
6a8e38941cea41fdb45f0d99dbab2753
```

Want the first 13 transaction go to the `for-each` controller at current I am using the variable name directly in loop controller. And the last file name exclude from the loop controller and sent it to another transaction which is `6a8e38941cea41fdb45f0d99dbab2753`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will have to switch to [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set the number of loops to use [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) like

```
${__intSum(${FileName_matchNr},-1,)}
```

and instead of output variable use the following expression:

```
${__V(FileName_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

And the last match can be referred using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like:

```
${__V(FileName_${FileName_matchNr},)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)